# Load embedded .net executable directly to memory, which will delete the calling executable proces filename from disc

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to load embedded .net executable directly to memory, which will delete the calling executable process filename from disk.

I have two executable file A and B

1. File B is embedded into FileA
2. File A should load it and call its method
3. File A exits.
4. Process from File B should delete File A and close.

Can method.Invoke be used in such scenerio?
I am not so sure if I can load assembly run and exit leaving it run?

I was thinking to do it along similar lines: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13897/Load-an-EXE-File-and-Run-It-from-Memory

But probably called Proces B will be active unless file A doesn't close itself.

Comment: I'm struggling to see your question here. That article gives you everything you need. You can read the file into memory as a byte array, close the stream (which will release the file handle) and load it entirely from memory, you should then be able to move/delete/overwrite the original file. Have you tried the code in the article?

Comment: Yep, Invoke is linked strongly with the calling assembly. When the executed assembly kills the original process it quits as well ...

Comment: Ah ok, perhaps it's worth adding that to the question? Silly question from me then I guess =]